# Can´t write in ddbb from form

Tags: database, model, getmodel

I make a new module which is a simply form, but i can not write into the ddbb, because (i think) can not find the model. I have this code in controllers/IndexController.php:

```
public function createPersonAction() {
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    $landing = Mage::getModel('landing/landing');
    $landing->setData('name', $data['name']);
    $landing->setData('apellido1', $data['apellido1']);
    $landing->setData('apellido2', $data['apellido2']);
    $landing->setData('email', $data['email']);
    $landing->setData('telefono', $data['telefono']);
    //$person->setData($data);
  try{
    $landing->save();
    $session->addSuccess('Add a person sucessfully');
  }catch(Exception $e){
    $session->addError('Add Error');
  }
$this->_redirect('landing');
}
```

But i have this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in \app\code\local\LP\Landing\controllers\IndexController.php on line 28
```

(Line 28 is --> $landing->setData('name', $data['name']);)

I have all the needed files, this is my tree:

```
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\Block\Index.php
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\Block\Adminhtml\Landingbackend.php
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\controllers\IndexController.php
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\controllers\Adminhtml\LandingbackendController.php
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\etc\config.xml
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\Helper\Data.php
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\Model\Landing.php
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\Model\Resource\Landing.php
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\Model\Resource\Landing\Collection.php
\app\code\local\LP\Landing\sql\landing_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have a problem in your module's config.xml file.

It should look something like this:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <landing>
            <class>LP_Landing_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>landing_resource</resourceModel>
        </landing>
        <landing_resource>
            <class>LP_Landing_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <landing>
                    <table>lp_landing_db_tablename</table>
                </landing>
            </entities>
        </landing_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <landing_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </landing_write>
        <landing_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </landing_read>
        <lp_landing_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>LP_Landing</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </lp_landing_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

You'll obviously need to change the `<table>lp_landing_db_tablename</table>` table name to whatever you specified in your `LP/Landing/sql/lp_landing_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` file.

You also may need to rename your install file from `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` to `install-0.1.0.php` for Magento to properly run the setup script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, great!

The lines that declared the table of the database were missing

```
        <entities>
            <landing>
                <table>lp_landing_db_tablename</table>
            </landing>
        </entities>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you're back on track.